# Prism detecting if page is modal programmatically and go back

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am implementing a feature using "connectivity" from essentials that when the app goes "offline" no wifi etc.. it navigates to a specific page.

It works in most cases however if I set the phone on "Airplane Mode" when I am on a  modal page it does not navigate to my page.

In Prism is there a way to detect if the current page "IsModal" and either goback or kill it so that I can navigate to my specific Page?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write some crazy lookup logic to figure it out. Unfortunately the helper for that doesn't currently exist. However the latest Prism 7.2 preview has some enhancements that specifically attempt to eliminate the need to figure out whether you require Modal Navigation and automatically use the proper type of Navigation. I would encourage you to try the preview. If you come up with a scenario where GoBack isn't working correctly please [open an issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/new/choose).

Comment: But not sure how 7.2 can help me in my specific case.All I want to do is "if notconnected go to this page"
but when modal it does not work.PageUtilities.DestroyPage did not work (me not understanding what is for) I was
hoping to remove modal from stack so that I could go to the page.
I have already been using 7.2 preview to have a feel of the changes required for "OnNavigatingTo".
Waiting for Official release + waiting for shell implementation once xf does their job.
Watched your twitch video and that helped a lot.Please keep doing them..
Fantastic job on Prism!!!!!